# Fatal error in array - Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
func getSelectedProductToCalc(countedProduct: [CountedProduct], index: Int)->Products?{
        let products = ((parent as! CallculatorViewController).parent as! MainViewControler).productsObjectArray
        if countedProduct[index].productCode != nil{
            if (products.count > 0 ){
                for cProduct in products {
                    if cProduct.code == countedProduct[index].productCode{
                        return cProduct
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            usedCalculatorLimit = products.count
            showAvailableProductPosition()
        }
        return nil
    }
```

I have error at below line:

`if countedProduct[index].productCode != nil{`

> - Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

At the start of the application, I do not know the size of the array (index). How can I protect this from displaying an error?
In case I do not have the necessary element in the table I would like to do: print ("empty!")

**UPDATED**

Ok, I'm updated any code to:

```
func getSelectedProductToCalc(countedProduct: [CountedProduct], index: Int)->Products?{
        let products = ((parent as! CallculatorViewController).parent as! MainViewControler).productsObjectArray

        if index < countedProduct.count && countedProduct[index].productCode != "" {
            if (products.count > 0 ){
                for cProduct in products {
                    if cProduct.code == countedProduct[index].productCode{
                        return cProduct
                    }
                }
            }
            usedCalculatorLimit = products.count
            showAvailableProductPosition()
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Now, when I run my function:

```
let product: Products = getSelectedProductToCalc(countedProduct: countedProductArray, index: 2)!
```

I have error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

How can you protect this?

Comment: _I do not know the size of the array_ - you can just get the size of the array?... `guard index < countedProduct.count else { return }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question. Just add a condition to check if the index is within your count.

```
if index < countedProduct.count && countedProduct[index].productCode != "" {
    //Do Something
}
```

Your result should also be optional or the function result should be safely unwrapped.

```
let product: Products? = getSelectedProductToCalc(countedProduct: countedProductArray, index: 2)
```

or

```
guard let product: Products = getSelectedProductToCalc(countedProduct: countedProductArray, index: 2) else {
    print("no products")
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before subscripting array with index check index is not out of bound from the array. So simply add one more condition with your if condition.

```
if index < countedProduct.count && countedProduct[index].productCode != nil {
    //Your code
}
```

**Suggestion :-** Also to check array is empty or not use [`isEmpty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688398-isempty) bool property.

Comment: Ok, I added an update to my code. btw why is it better to use: isEmpty instead of .count?

Comment: @traff Your function return type is optional and you are force wrapping the result thats why your app is crashing use `if let`or `guard let` for conditional binding. Like this. `if let product  = getSelectedProductToCalc(countedProduct: countedProductArray, index: 2) { //access product object here }`

Comment: @traff I'm suggesting to use `isEmpty` because it will simply give you bool answer that array is empty or not, there is no need to get count and then check `count == 0`

Answer (score 0):

It's showing this error because of you are trying to access the array value beyond the array data.

So you need to check, that index should be always less then the array count.

Just add the following code at the first line of your method:

```
guard index < countedProduct.count else { return nil }
```

Hope this will help you. :)